# How to read an output file in one command line?

Tags: command-line, firefox

How to do something like this correctly?

```
$: lshw -html > /tmp/specs.html < firefox
```

also tried

```
$: firefox < "lshw -html > /tmp/specs.html"
```

Comment: thanks , it worked  . But the html appeared like as a source  like this                                                       ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="generator"  content="lshw-B.02.18" />
<style type="text/css">
  .first {font-weight: bold; margin-left: none; padding-right: 1em;vertical-align: top; } .......

Comment: @SebastianStark data uri not working anymore, get blocking from top level navigation, due security bug

Answer (score 6):

You should output lshw to a file, and open that file with firefox, as follows:

```
lshw -html >/tmp/specs.html && firefox /tmp/specs.html
```

Or

```
sudo lshw -html >/tmp/specs.html && firefox /tmp/specs.html
```

Update: Following not uses temp files, but need bcat
Install bcat package:

```
sudo apt install ruby-bcat
```

Then the command you want is simple

```
lshw -html|bcat -b firefox
```

`bcat` help output:

> Pipe to browser utility. Read standard input, possibly one or more
>   s, and write concatenated / formatted output to browser.

Comment: thanks for the answer , but I don't want to write the filename again

Comment: I mean , I want to use the output file "specs.html"  as an input for the command firefox

Comment: Would using a variable solve your issue? e.g. `FILE="/tmp/specs.html"; lshw -html > $FILE && firefox $FILE`.

Comment: thanks , but this is the same ,, you wrote $FILE  twice

Comment: ``$ echo <(lshw -html)`` produces "_/dev/fd/63_",  ``wc -l <(lshw -html) /dev/null`` produces "_471 /dev/fd/63 ..._".  So why does ``firefox <(lshw -html)`` produce "_Firefox can’t find the file at /dev/fd/pipe_"?

Comment: @RayButterworth try `ls -l <(lshw -html)` -- procfs makes /dev/fd/NN look like a symlink to something with the apparent name `pipe:[numbergoeshere]`, and Firefox gets confused when it tries to interpret that name.

Comment: @MostafaEsmail Updated answer. With bcat you don't need to write to file at all

Comment: @LeonidMew , thanks a lot , bcat made it . 